# How much online space will I need to store online players information?

Tags: online-storage

I want to save the players information by using free online storage such as Google Drive or Mediafire or something similar, I just wonder if the free space of Google Drive (15GB right now?) is enough for me to save all the user's information when they exit the game? (assume that the game got support from players and grow big enough to 50000 players) such as current items, stage of items, amount of zen,current quest, current level current exp, current location, current skills and skill level, current unlocked achievement ...? if it is not, then usually how much online space is enough to save the information of 50000+ accounts ?

I will create a simple online game which will be publishing for free (free to download, no ads, no in-game purchase or DownLoadableContent) in both Android market, App Store, and Steam. I'm a new developer so this game will be a good practice for me.

p/s: I have no ideal which free service can I use to save the players information beside using online storage(google, mediafire,..so on...), if there is any better way to save players information for an online game, please give me a suggestion.

Comment: If you are using android , its better to use firebase  by google which is free to some extent. For web or desktop applications relational databases like sql server or mysql are used .. So in short you cannot utilize that google drive storage more efficiently .

Comment: is there any way to estimate the size of space I will need for the game ? if the users data is around 50000 ?